# Whic file of my C# project i wll give to a user for just use my software but they cant modified it

Tags: c#-3.0

im making a software using C#.net ..and want to give it to users
Which file of my C# project i should give to a user for just use my software but they cant modified it.....how i make that type of file?

Comment: The only foolproof way to not let your users modify your files is to not give them the files.

Answer (score 1):

> Which file of my C# project i should
>   give to a user

You should give **none** of the files that are part of your C# project. Provide only the compiled assemblies or if you already have a setup project that generates a deployment package such as an MSI, provide the resulting MSI.

Answer (score 0):

You must create setup file and provide that much only.And your set up must contains serial key.If you dont know how to create serial key during setup creation then [click here](http://rupeshit.webs.com/apps/blog/entries/show/2443621-setup-and-deployment-and-give-serialkey-in-net)